# I don't know how to select specific items from json object in my web application using flask

Tags: python, flask, jsonify

```
response = requests.get(url)
response_json = response.json()
results = response_json['a'][0]
output = results['a_1'] + results['a_2'] + results['a_3']
return jsonify(output)
```

my output
"abcdefg"

what I want
abcdefg

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jsonify` builds a Flask Response object.  With this code you're trying to access it as if it was a dictionary:

```
results = jsonify( response_json )["results"][0]  # bad
```

I think you're looking for:

```
results  = jsonify( response_json["results"[0] )
```

Note that here `response_json` is actually a python datastructure (a dictionary) because that's what `response.json` returns.

Comment: Thank you v25 now I can return the address, but now I have another problem. I return the address like "somewhere" but I want it as somewhere, I mean without double quotation. How should I do ?

Comment: @西山功一 I suggest logging another question for this, to keep each question tidy.  Please give a good sample of your code, actual output and excepted output.  See [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @西山功一 If you're returning json then `"abcdefg"` is a valid json, `abcdefg` is not.  You're question doesn't metion how the frontend is loading this.  Really the frontend should deal with the display part.  Perhaps you should be investigating the `render_template` function to display something user-friendly in the browser.  This is hard to answer without the extra info.

Comment: Okay I'm new to programming so I don't exactly know what 'how the frontend is loading this' mean, but I'm creating a web app using heroku and when I open the web application I want to return the output without "". I mean to display output without "".